# npm run start does not compile sass or run live-server. Going on an infinite loop with weird message

Tags: npm, sass, compass-sass, npm-scripts, node-sass

I've been trying to run a sass project with the following devDependencies and Scripts. When i try to run npm run start, it fails with an error as shown in the screenshot.

package.json file :

```
"main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix:css compress:css"
  },
  "author": "name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.4",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^4.1.1"
  }
```

And I get the below response when tried to run npm run start

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW74b.png)

I use node v14.17.3, and npm 8.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Intentional bug from the developer of color.js https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/285 that is being worked on. Pin to 1.4.0 or set a resolution as described in https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/285#issuecomment-1008168237